# NetSuite redirect fails with bad SAML request on Azure

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, netsuite, azure-active-directory

I have setup SSO with Netsuite and Azure using the following instructions:

> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-netsuite-tutorial/.

The SSO works for users from Office 365 to NetSuite, however if a user clicks on a NetSuite link in an email they receive an invalid SAML protocol message from Azure during authentication.

For example:
Email Link is

> "https:\system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/purchord.nl?id=167770&c={ACCOUNT_ID}"

Get redirected to (by NetSuite)

> "https:\login.windows.net/9621cdc8-e1c4-4a3c-849e-35be6db5a45e/saml2"

which then redirects to :

> "https:\login.microsoftonline.com/9621cdc8-e1c4-4a3c-849e-35be6db5a45e/saml2?RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fsystem.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Faccounting%2Ftransactions%2Fpurchord.nl%3Fid%3D167770%26c%3D{ACCOUNT_ID}"

which generates error:

Sign In
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: a8ceee9f-8507-4f55-aa56-e65266bf7d92
Timestamp: 2016-04-13 05:18:07Z
AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid Saml2 protocol message.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get further details on the error, or fix it?

Comment: Is it `https:\ `  or  `https:\\ ` in your code?

Comment: I don't see any `SAMLRequest` query parameter in `https:\\login.microsoftonline.com/9621cdc8-e1c4-4a3c-849e-35be6db5a45e/saml2?RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fsystem.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Faccounting%2Ftransactions%2Fpurchord.nl%3Fid%3D167770%26c%3D{ACCOUNT_ID}` Have you intentionally trimmed this URL? If yes, can you provide the complete URL?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the exact same issue with our instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and found a solution that works for me.

Try using the following format

[https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/signin/{AZURE](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/signin/%7BAZURE) NETSUITE - APPLICATION_ID}?RelayState=https%3A%2F%2F{NetSuite_Account#}.app.netsuite.com%2Fapp%2Faccounting%2Ftransactions%2Fpurchord.nl%3Fid%3D{Purchae_Order_Record_ID}

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I faced this issue with Azure SSO, link does not work it fails @ the SSO provider's(Azure) login URL. Issue is not with the Netsuite it is sending the request for authentication to Azure but Azure could not authenticate the user even though user is logged into the AD. You can resolve this issue by syncing Azure AD and source of authority. Also make sure your Azure SSo is setup correctly -by running zure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell as an admin.

Good luck